# How to display a set number of rows in small Table View with self-sizing cells

Tags: swift, uikit, tableview

I have a custom table view class, which is configured to set the table view height to display only 3 rows. This means if there are 20 rows, table view will be sized to display first 3 rows, and allowing user to scroll.

This code of mine works only if I set the static `rowHeight`

```
class CannedRepliesTableView: UITableView {

    /// The max visible rows visible in the autocomplete table before the user has to scroll throught them
    let maxVisibleRows = 3

    open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {

        let rows = numberOfRows(inSection: 0) < maxVisibleRows ? numberOfRows(inSection: 0) : maxVisibleRows
        return CGSize(width: super.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: (CGFloat(rows) * rowHeight))
    }
}
```

If I set `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to the `rowHeight`, table view is not properly resized. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Since the cells are self sizing, how do you know all cells have equal heights? How can you determine the height needed to show any 3 cells at a time when scrolling can find a cell that's sized differently?

Comment: Well, that is my problem :( I want intrinsic size to set to the height of first 3 cells. Is there no solution to this? If not, I must set the rowHeight to fixed value then :(

Answer (score 1):

This would be one way to improve on what you currently have. I don't have experience accessing `intrinsicContentSize` for this calculations and didn't test this locally (other than syntax), but if previously it worked, this should as well.

Basically you're creating an array with `maxVisibleRows` number of **indexPaths**. If you have less, then `fetchedIndexesCount` prevents an **indexOutOfBounds** crash. Once you have the array, you iterate for each corresponding cell and fetching its size, finally summing it up.

```
class CannedRepliesTableView: UITableView {

    var focussedSection = 0
    let maxVisibleRows = 3

    open override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: super.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: calculateHeight())
    }

    private func calculateHeight() -> CGFloat {
        guard let indexPaths = startIndexes(firstCount: 3) else {
            // Your table view doesn't have any rows. Feel free to return a non optional and remove this check if confident there's always at least a row
            return 0
        }
        return indexPaths.compactMap({ cellForRow(at: $0)?.intrinsicContentSize.height }).reduce(0, +)
    }

    private func startIndexes(firstCount x: Int) -> [IndexPath]? {
        let rowsCount = numberOfRows(inSection: focussedSection)
        let fetchedIndexesCount = min(x, rowsCount)
        guard fetchedIndexesCount > 0 else {
            return nil
        }
        var result = [IndexPath]()
        for i in 0..<fetchedIndexesCount {
            result.append(IndexPath(row: i, section: focussedSection))
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and although it works ok with getting cells and stuff, it gets 0 height from table view cells with the dynamic dimensions. Anyways, thanks for the help, I will use static height in order to achieve this

Comment: I think you could have a look at replacing checks for intrinsicContentSize.height with `systemLayoutSizeFitting(CGSize(width: providedWidth, height: 0)).height`

Comment: Well, it turns out it is much simpler in my case to use fixed width, instead of the automatic-sizing. Thanks anyways for your help